# Numbers to array json format

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have the variable that holds numbers...before writing it to database it must be in this format:

```
["1", "6", "11", "15"]
```

I got this from my ajax call:

```
1,6,11,15
```

I try to convert string with numbers to array...and now one way is to foreach to read from array and add to beginning and ending string `"` but i think that is bad idea...could be simpler way to archive this above output?

```
$numbers = '1,6,11,15';

$a = str_split($numbers);

print_r($a);
```

Comment: Possible [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). How's that data being generated / sent?

Comment: your required format is `json`. you should use `json_encode` with `explode with comma` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$numbers = '1,6,11,15';

$a = explode(",",$numbers);

echo json_encode($a);
```